# Search a site for a link with Google?

Tags: google-search

Can you use Google to search a site for a specific link? I dont know if it would be a relative or absolute link but its an internal link to that domain.

Another solution to my issue (but not quite as good) would be to test if a page is indexed by google.

Comment: Google something like that: `http://example.com/some/link/to/file.txt`? If the page is indexed it will be in the results I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for indexed page with the prefix "site" -  `site:http://domain.com/category/product/`, of course you can see all indexed pages from a domain with `site:domain.com`